# Auto install programs in cronological order

Tags: automation, installation, malware-detection

I wanted to know if i can automate the installation and automatically run programs as soon as i plug in the usb... or maybe clock on an auto-run file.... I'm basically trying to auto run malware removal program (multiple programs) and tell the windows to go into safe mode(automatically). Is there a way i can automate this process.

question: if such things can be automated, can I make some sort of program which automatically downloads from the web and run it?

I've searched online for this but didn't find what i was looking for. If anyone can help we that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are trying to do this on a windows machine you won't have much luck. Microsoft blocked autorun on USB a long time ago. However I do know about the Sandisk U3 USB drives that used to act like a CD and run a setup.exe. However, to my knowledge, Microsoft has since blocked that as well.

You can find more information on this here:
http://portableapps.com/node/31519